# Want to move entire folder using Net :: Ftp on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have rails application, which sends file to FTP. I want to move entire folder to Ftp, but it's giving this error:

```
/home/Anup/code/DashGo-2.2.0/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/runner.rb:47: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:471:in `gets': Is a directory - /home/Anup/code/DashGo-2.2.0/private/temp_file (Errno::EISDIR)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:471:in `storlines'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:470:in `loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:470:in `storlines'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:467:in `storlines'
```

I am using `Net::FTP` rails gem.

Is any method available in ruby which gives the list of all files given the folder name?

Answer (score 2):

FTP (in general - not just the ruby gem) has never been good at transferring directories.  In fact, I'm not sure that it's ever supported it.

Take a look at SCP instead.  That's what I ended up using to transfer directories between a couple of my computers.  In ruby, there's even a [Net::SCP](http://net-ssh.github.com/scp/v1/api/classes/Net/SCP.html) class that should correspond nicely to the Net::FTP class you're currently using.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Also I think that Net::Scp is better solution, but sometimes is not possible to use it. In this case I use [FTPSync](https://github.com/ashchan/ftpsync) ... but is very sloooooooooow (as FTP is slow) in big directories

```
ftpconn = FtpSync.new(<host>, <user>, <pass>)
ftpconn.verbose = true
ftpconn.push_dir(@local_path,@remote_path)
```